# NLog Extended AspNetBufferingWrapper not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7, httpmodule, nlog

I have the following target in my web.config using the AspNetBufferingWrapper wrapper of NLog Extended

```
<wrapper-target type="ASPNetBufferingWrapper" name="aspNetBuffer">
    <wrapper-target type="PostFilteringWrapper" name="postFilter" defaultFilter="level >= LogLevel.Debug">
      <target-ref name="logDB" />
      <when exists="level >= LogLevel.Warn" filter="level >= LogLevel.Trace" />
    </wrapper-target>
  </wrapper-target>
```

The target-ref is working without wrappers or with other wrappers.
I have the httpmodule as the documentation recommends

```
<httpModules>
  <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
  <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" />
  <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" />
  <add name="NLog" type="NLog.Web.NLogHttpModule, NLog.Extended" />
</httpModules>
```

I have it configured in a MVC3 project with NLog.2.0.0.2000 and NLog.Extended.2.0.0.2000.

I have included the elmah module to point out that that module is working.
After searching around I found that IIS 7 in integrated mode uses the system.webServer modules. I have noticed that the elmah module already has this section configured, so I included NLog.Extended has well.

```
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="NLog" type="NLog.Web.NLogHttpModule, NLog.Extended" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
```

Well, it did not work as well... I have activated the internal Nlog logger in Trace mode and I see the following:

```
2013-03-19 16:06:58.2933 Trace Sending buffered events to wrapped target: PostFilteringWrapper Target[postFilter](AsyncWrapper Target[logDB](Database Target[logDB_wrapped])).
2013-03-19 16:06:58.2933 Trace Running PostFilteringWrapper Target[postFilter](AsyncWrapper Target[logDB](Database Target[logDB_wrapped])) on 0 events
2013-03-19 16:06:58.3053 Trace Filter to apply: (level >= Debug)
2013-03-19 16:06:58.3053 Trace After filtering: 0 events.
```

I can't remember what else to do/search. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The reason only the logfile from the `AsyncWrapper` are written, is because your `ASPNetBufferingWrapper` and `AsyncWrapper` has the same name. Also you File targets have the same name.

But this can only been seen when looking at your config file, http://pastebin.com/3cP83PWa posted on the [NLog issues page](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/194)

If you targets have unique names both files will be written.